# How to execute a script on every allocated node with PBS

Tags: pbs

I want to execute a script on every node that is allocated to my job. So I did the following test.

```
#PBS -N Test
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=4

ulimit -Ss unlimited

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
cp $PBS_NODEFILE node
NCORE=`cat node | wc -l`
export P4_RSHCOMMAND=/opt/pbs/default/bin/pbs_remsh
echo `hostname` > `hostname`
```

The result is `` echo `hostname` > `hostname` `` is only executed on the first allocated node.

What I actually want to do is

```
#PBS -N Test
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=4

ulimit -Ss unlimited

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
cp $PBS_NODEFILE node
NCORE=`cat node | wc -l`
export P4_RSHCOMMAND=/opt/pbs/default/bin/pbs_remsh
jug execute somescript&
jug execute somescript&
jug execute somescript&
jug execute somescript&
```

in which the four `jug execute somescript&` is executed on every node. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Torque, there is an easy was to do this is:

```
pbsdsh -u somescript
```