# How to convert a script that uses ssh to pbsdsh while using Ray?

Tags: python, ssh, ray

I am stuck with converting my script that uses ssh to activate nodes to pbsdsh. I am using Ray for node communication. My script with ssh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N Experiment_1
#PBS -l select=2:ncpus=24:mpiprocs=24
#PBS -P CSCIxxxx
#PBS -q normal
#PBS -l walltime=01:30:00
#PBS -m abe
#PBS -M xxxxx@gmail.com

ln -s $PWD $PBS_O_WORKDIR/$PBS_JOBID

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

jobnodes=`uniq -c ${PBS_NODEFILE} | awk -F. '{print $1 }' | awk '{print $2}' | paste -s -d " "`

thishost=`uname -n | awk -F. '{print $1.}'`
thishostip=`hostname -i`
rayport=6379
 
thishostNport="${thishostip}:${rayport}"
echo "Allocate Nodes = <$jobnodes>"
export thishostNport
 
echo "set up ray cluster..." 
for n in `echo ${jobnodes}`
do
        if [[ ${n} == "${thishost}" ]]
        then
                echo "first allocate node - use as headnode ..."
                module load chpc/python/anaconda/3-2019.10
                source /apps/chpc/chem/anaconda3-2019.10/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
                conda activate /home/mnasir/env1
                ray start --head
                sleep 5
        else
                ssh ${n}  $PBS_O_WORKDIR/startWorkerNode.pbs ${thishostNport}
                sleep 10
        fi
done 
 
python -u example_trainer.py 

rm $PBS_O_WORKDIR/$PBS_JOBID
#
```

where startWorkerNode.pbs is:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
source $HOME/.bashrc
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
param1=$1
destnode=`uname -n`
echo "destnode is = [$destnode]"
module load chpc/python/anaconda/3-2019.10
source /apps/chpc/chem/anaconda3-2019.10/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate /home/mnasir/poet
ray start --address="${param1}" --redis-password='5241590000000000'
```

and the example_trainer.py is:

```
from collections import Counter
import os
import socket
import sys
import time
import ray

num_cpus = int(sys.argv[1])

ray.init(address=os.environ["thishostNport"])

print("Nodes in the Ray cluster:")
print(ray.nodes()) # This should print all N nodes we are trying to access


@ray.remote
def f():
    time.sleep(1)
    return socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) + "--" + str(socket.gethostname())


# The following takes one second (assuming that
# ray was able to access all of the allocated nodes).
for i in range(60):
    start = time.time()
    ip_addresses = ray.get([f.remote() for _ in range(num_cpus)])
    print("GOT IPs", ip_addresses)
    print(Counter(ip_addresses))
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
```

This works perfectly and communicates across all nodes but when I try to change the command to pbsds it returns:

```
pbsdsh: task 0x00000000 exit status 254
pbsdsh: task 0x00000001 exit status 254
```

when `mpiprocs=1` and if it is set to `24` it repeats 48 times.

As per the best of my knowledge, ray needs a host node and then worker nodes are connected to it and thus the for loop and if statement in it.

I have tried directly replacing `pbsdsh` in the script with/without identifying nodes. I have added pbsdsh out of the loop and tried a whole lot of possible combinations.

I have followed these questions but could not get my code to communicate throughout nodes:

- [PBS/TORQUE: how do I submit a parallel job on multiple nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881147/pbs-torque-how-do-i-submit-a-parallel-job-on-multiple-nodes/30891254#30891254)
- [How to execute a script on every allocated node with PBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591121/how-to-execute-a-script-on-every-allocated-node-with-pbs/33697452#33697452)
- [Handle multiple nodes in one pbs job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171666/handle-multiple-nodes-in-one-pbs-job)

I believe there might be something not too big that I am not able to implement. Your help and guidance will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few main things that needed to change to solve this problem:

1. `#PBS -l select=2:ncpus=24:mpiprocs=1` should be used as the selector line, specifically, change `mpiprocs` from `24` to `1`, so that `pbsdsh` only launches one process per node instead of 24.
2. Inside `jobscript.sh`, inside the `else`, you can use `pbsdsh -n $J -- $PBS_O_WORKDIR/startWorkerNode.pbs ${thishostNport} &` to run pbsdsh only on one node, and in the background. `J` is kept as a node index and is incremented at each iteration of the for loop. This results in the `ray start` being run on each node once.
3. Inside `startWorkerNode.pbs`, add this code at the end

```
# Here, sleep for the duration of the job, so ray does not stop
WALLTIME=$(qstat -f $PBS_JOBID | sed -rn 's/.*Resource_List.walltime = (.*)/\1/p')
SECONDS=`echo $WALLTIME | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'`
echo "SLEEPING FOR $SECONDS s"
sleep $SECONDS
```

This ensures that the `ray start` does not exit as soon as the `pbsdsh` command returns and is kept alive for the duration of the job. The `&` in the previous point is also necessary here, as `pbsdsh` will never return without it.

Here are the files for reference:

#### startWorkerNode.pbs

```
#!/bin/bash -l
source $HOME/.bashrc
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
param1=$1
destnode=`uname -n`
echo "destnode is = [$destnode]"
module load chpc/python/anaconda/3-2019.10
source /apps/chpc/chem/anaconda3-2019.10/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate /home/mnasir/poet
ray start --address="${param1}" --redis-password='5241590000000000'
# Here, sleep for the duration of the job, so ray does not stop
WALLTIME=$(qstat -f $PBS_JOBID | sed -rn 's/.*Resource_List.walltime = (.*)/\1/p')
SECONDS=`echo $WALLTIME | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'`
echo "SLEEPING FOR $SECONDS s"
sleep $SECONDS
```

#### jobscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N Experiment_1
#PBS -l select=2:ncpus=24:mpiprocs=1
#PBS -P CSCIxxxx
#PBS -q normal
#PBS -l walltime=01:30:00
#PBS -m abe
#PBS -M xxxxx@gmail.com

ln -s $PWD $PBS_O_WORKDIR/$PBS_JOBID

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

jobnodes=`uniq -c ${PBS_NODEFILE} | awk -F. '{print $1 }' | awk '{print $2}' | paste -s -d " "`

thishost=`uname -n | awk -F. '{print $1.}'`
thishostip=`hostname -i`
rayport=6379
 
thishostNport="${thishostip}:${rayport}"
echo "Allocate Nodes = <$jobnodes>"
export thishostNport
 
echo "set up ray cluster..." 
J=0
for n in `echo ${jobnodes}`
do
        if [[ ${n} == "${thishost}" ]]
        then
                echo "first allocate node - use as headnode ..."
                module load chpc/python/anaconda/3-2019.10
                source /apps/chpc/chem/anaconda3-2019.10/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
                conda activate /home/mnasir/env1
                ray start --head
                sleep 5
        else
                # Run pbsdsh on the J'th node, and do it in the background.
        pbsdsh -n $J -- $PBS_O_WORKDIR/startWorkerNode.pbs ${thishostNport} &
                sleep 10
        fi
J=$((J+1))
done 


python -u example_trainer.py 48

rm $PBS_O_WORKDIR/$PBS_JOBID
```